# How to configure META-QT5 layer to build META-TOOLCHAIN-QT to cross compile Yocto for MINNOWBOARD

Tags: qt5, qt-creator, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake

I need to run a software application on top of the yocto image I'm building for Minnowboard. The main configuration needed is Qt5.

I was able to build a sample test image for Minnowboard according to the latest yocto guide by adding meta-intel layer with MACHINE intel-corei7-64 and EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "dev-pkgs"

But I'm having trouble with building Qt support for my yocto image. I added [meta-qt5](https://code.qt.io/cgit/yocto/meta-qt5.git/) layer and tried to **compile for meta-toolchain-qt5** so that according to this [guide](https://www.ics.com/blog/configuring-qt-creator-yocto-development) I can setup Qt-creator in my host machine to cross compile for Minnowboard.

But meta-toolchain-qt5 is keep failing with many errors.

> Summary: 7 tasks failed:
>     /home/holoplot/Yocto/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/**qtwebsockets_git**.bb:do_compile
>     /home/holoplot/Yocto/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/**qtenginio_git**.bb:do_install
>     /home/holoplot/Yocto/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/**qtgraphicaleffects_git**.bb:do_compile
>     /home/holoplot/Yocto/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/**qt3d_git**.bb:do_compile
>     /home/holoplot/Yocto/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/**qtconnectivity_git**.bb:do_compile
>     /home/holoplot/Yocto/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/**qtquickcontrols2_git**.bb:do_compile
>     /home/holoplot/Yocto/poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/**qtsensors_git**.bb:do_compile

ATM, I'm using **PYRO** branch for all layers. I added following layers (**openembedded-core/meta** , **meta-openembedded/meta-oe** , **meta-openembedded/meta-ruby** , **meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia** in hope of a successful meta-toolchain-qt5 build but it still failed.

Is there a stable branch that I can use to successfully build the meta-toolchain-qt5 for minnowboard or should I edit the qt recipes in order to avoid building above packages which causes errors?

Any support is much appreciated. Thanks!

FYI : My software has following dependencies.

> linux-vdso.so.1
>       libnetsnmp.so.30
>       **libQt5Network**.so.5
>       **libQt5Network**.so.5
>       **libQt5Core.so.5**
>       libpthread.so.0
>       libstdc++.so.6
>       libstdc++.so.6
>       libm.so.6
>       libgcc_s.so.1
>       libc.so.6
>       libz.so.1
>       **libicui18n**.so.56
>       **libicuuc**.so.56
>       **libicudata**.so.56
>       libdl.so.2
>       libgthread-2.0.so.0
>       libglib-2.0.so.0
>       libglib-2.0.so.0
>       libpcre.so.3

Comment: Well, could you state what errors your getting?

Comment: Better show all your errors; The last time I compile Pyro had no errors at all for imx6;

Comment: here's the complete log.  [link](https://ufile.io/pkolq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error log.  This seem like has no problem with the recipe but instead the spec of your machine;  Please try to increase the amount of RAM for your virtual machine;

> 440589a074-r0/git/src/core/jobs/qthreadpooler.cpp
> | compiling /home/holoplot/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/qt3d/5.8.0+gitAUTOINC+440589a074-r0/git/src/core/jobs/task.cpp
>
> | virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
> | virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory

I recommend to have at least 4G of RAM for a dual core processor;

> | NOTE: make -j 16 MAKEFLAGS=-j 16
> OE_QMAKE_COMPILER=x86_64-poky-linux-gcc  -m64 -march=corei7
> -mtune=corei7 -mfpmath=sse -msse4.2 --sysroot=/home/holoplot/Yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/qtgraphicaleffects/5.8.0+gitAUTOINC+1583bb5569-r0/recipe-sysroot
> OE_QMAKE_CC=x86_64-poky-linux-gcc  -m64 -march=corei7 -mtune=corei

`make -j4 16 MAKEFLAGS = -j 16`  There are 2 possibilities here;

-You set to compile with 16 threads;  If this is the case, set the threads with these variables;

```
BB_NUMBER_THREADS ?= "${@oe.utils.cpu_count()}"
PARALLEL_MAKE ?= "-j ${@oe.utils.cpu_count()}"
```

-You are currently using a 16 core machine.  In Amazon EC2, this type of M4.4xlarge instance has 64G RAM, which is more than enough to compile Yocto;

Comment: Hi @Charles! thanks for the reply and your observation. I am bitbaking on a virtual machine (Ubuntu 16) on a local server. I had given 16 cores but only 4 GB to the VM before. When I increased it to 16GB, I did not get the **virtual memory exhausted** error anymore.

Comment: Then I got an undefined reference error related to **qtquickcontrols2** error log [here] (https://ufile.io/qfr00) . I was able to bypass it for the timebeing by removing **qtquickcontrols2 \ qtquickcontrols2-dev \ qtquickcontrols2-mkspecs** from the **poky/meta-qt5/recipes-qt/packagegroups/packagegroup-qt5-toolchain-target.bb** . But then I ended up towards the end at this error which shows conflict between **nativesdk-cmake and nativesdk-qtbase** . here's the [error log](https://ufile.io/ub016) Although I'm able to bitbake cmake and qtbase separately. Any suggestions? Thanks for your support!

Comment: delete the tmp folder. run `bitbake -c cleansstate qtbase` and then `bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5` to see if there is still errors

Comment: changing PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_ipk" from package_rpm solved the conflict between cmake and qtbase. Thanks everyone for your support!:)